# Heroku: no module named flask though it is in requirements.txt

Tags: heroku, deployment, flask

Can anyone help with this error on Heroku?

```
2015-01-12T22:26:00.575669+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python hangman.py`
2015-01-12T22:26:01.066240+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2015-01-12T22:26:01.066256+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "hangman.py", line 3, in <module>
2015-01-12T22:26:01.066262+00:00 app[web.1]:     from flask import (
2015-01-12T22:26:01.066268+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: No module named flask
2015-01-12T22:26:01.742444+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-01-12T22:26:01.751614+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

My git repo is here: https://github.com/PJBentham/Hangman

I believe I have done everything correct as far as set up is concerned but I'm still getting the above error and can't figure out why?

Comment: Do you have the entire Heroku log? Somewhere in the log there should be the processing of the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You have to show the last or pull `traceback` to debug further ...! You git repo working perfectly fine.

From your traceback snippet `flask` is not there. Check if your app environ having flask or not using  `heroku run pip freeze`

Comment: Hi @Raja, thanks for answering. I ended up getting this working. There must have been a fault with my requirements.txt file as I copied and pasted the example folder and added flask to that rather thamn using pip freeze > requirements.txt and it worked thereafter.

Comment: I am having the same problem here but these are my logs... I dont understand

appdirs==1.4.3
Flask==0.10.1
Flask-API==0.7.1
google-api-python-client==1.6.2
gunicorn==19.7.1
httplib2==0.10.3
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.9.6
Markdown==2.6.8
MarkupSafe==1.0
oauth2client==4.0.0
packaging==16.8
pyasn1==0.2.3
pyasn1-modules==0.0.8
pyparsing==2.2.0
python-dateutil==2.6.0
rsa==3.4.2
six==1.10.0
uritemplate==3.0.0
Werkzeug==0.12.1

Comment: @PaulBentham I did both but still have this damn error. Yet, the error seemed to be different when using `freeze`